# При скачивании файла сохраняется 0 кб

Tags: php

Мне нужно скачать docx (pdf) файл с сайта, но при это когда он сохраняется, его размер равен 0кб. Для скачивания использую следующий код

```
$file = '../documents/' . $url[1];
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit();
```

Файл .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

UPD: Не работает напрямую по ссылке или через просмот директории, а также на сторонних локальный сайтах. Используется OpenServer

Comment: а пхп тут какую роль призван решать в данном процессе? почему не скачать без его участия?

Comment: @teran человек тренируется отдавать таким способом

Comment: `readfile` не находит файл... То-есть по сути ты заголовки отправил, а сам файл потерялся в пустыне жесткого диска. Проверь правильность `$file = '../documents/' . $url[1];` . PS:   `НИКОГДА НЕ ПРОПУСКАЙ НЕ ПРОВЕРЕННЫЙ ИНПУТ!`    пользователь хитрый в $url[1] может отправить например `../../../../etc/shadow` и получить вместо doc файла, файл с пользователями OS. Или чего ещё похуже.

Comment: @teran при скачивании напрямую или скачивании прямо с директории, все равно сохраняется 0 кб

Comment: так может там и файл 0 размера по факту лежит?

Comment: @teran если руками его открыть, без скачивания, то все нормально, но при скачке его размер 0 и он поврежден. Не работает напрямую по ссылке или через просмот директории, а также на сторонних локальный сайтах. Используется OpenServer

Comment: @teran может ли браузер не качать из-за отсутствия https?

Comment: Советую для начала проверить, действительно ли вы можете потрогать целевой файл, можно так: `$path = realpath($pathToFile); if ($path && file_exists($path)) { тут можно отправлять, до этого, нельзя быть уверенным, что все идет по плану }`

Comment: Так же, проверьте, что вы хоть что-то прочитали из файла: `if (!$bytes = readfile($path)) { возвращает кол-во прочитанных байт или же false }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот несколько советов, при выполнении которых не обещаю, но скорее всего заработает:

1. Для начала проверить, действительно ли вы можете потрогать целевой файл, можно так: `$path = realpath($pathToFile); if ($path && file_exists($path) && is_readable($path)) { тут можно отправлять, до этого, нельзя быть уверенным, что все идет по плану }`
2. Так же, проверьте, что вы хоть что-то прочитали из файла: `if (!$bytes = readfile($path)) { возвращает кол-во прочитанных байт или же false }`.
3. Перед отправкой файла стоит убедится, что буферизация вывода отключена, можно сделать с помощью `ob_get_level()` или сбросить и отключить ее функцией `ob_end_clean()`.
4. Заголовок: `header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');` - хоть и сказано, что это больше к MIME, нежели чем к HTTP, многие примеры имеют реализацию с ним, советую попробовать.

В остальном, можно посмотреть на [рабочие примеры](https://snipp.ru/php/send-download), если и они откажутся у вас работать, то стоит посмотреть на окружение, права и настройку самого веб-сервера.